# Quoted star in command not behaving as expected

Tags: bash

In Bash I have a function in my profile:

`FCT () { /usr/bin/someProg -id=myUser -pa=myPass $*; }`

Now I can perfectly start the someProg and do what I want.
But when I want to use it like this:

`FCT -comma 'select * from table'`

Is is ignoring the single-quotes and replacing the * with all files in the current directory

`FCT -comma select \* from table`

Does the same... the escape is ignored

When set +f/-f it goes as expected, but is unwanted as it must be easy for the team.
Any idea why the single quotes and -escape is ignored?

Comment: try replacing `$*` with `"$@"`  with quotes, like what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why the single quotes and -escape is ignored?

Because `$*` expands [each parameter separated by the first character in IFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) and after that the result also undergoes [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting). So the resulting arguments will be separated by spaces, tabs and newlines, no matter the content.

Use `"$@"`.